# var_dump() shows array but is_array() is false

Tags: php, simplexml

`$response` is a SimpleXML element and an initial var_dump shows it as an array but I can't loop through it.  It turns into an object when I access it specifically.

Any suggestions?

```
    var_dump($response); //shows KeyResult as array
    if (is_array($response->KeyResult)) { //returns false
        $addressRankings = array();
        foreach ($response->KeyResult as $rating) {
            print_r($rating);
```

Here's the var_dump

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (1) {
  ["KeyResult"]=>
  array(10) {
    [0]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (5) {
```

Comment: you mean its also not empty?

Comment: Why can't you replace it with `if ($response->KeyResult instanceof \Traversable)`?

Comment: What does `var_dump($response->KeyResult)` show?

Comment: this code `$response->KeyResult` treats $response like an object, not an array

Comment: @ekims Yes, `$response` is an object, it's `$response->KeyResult` that should be an array

Comment: if you post the `var_dump`, we could probably help more

Comment: What does the XML look like?

Comment: `var_dump($response->KeyResult);` - stop guessing and check exactly

Comment: @zerkms Been there, done that, it's an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var_dump` dumps the SimpleXML object content, but when you call `->KeyResult` it has more magic (like __get method), which returns not [an array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php#example-5288):

> Properties ($movies->movie in previous example) are not arrays. They
>   are iterable and accessible objects.

Comment: If you want to know if you can use `foreach` do `if (is_array($var) || $var instanceof Traversable)`.